# Proof of limit of function in absolute value

Tags: calculus, limits, absolute-value

I have the following question, and not sure if its a true or false statement. Couldn't construct a proof but couldn't construct a counter example either...

> If $\lim \limits_{x \to a} |f(x)| = L$ for some $L≥0$ then either $\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ or $\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x) = -L$ .

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $L = 0$, the statement is true.  This is built into the definition of limit.  Because saying $f(x)$ is close to $0$ is the same thing as saying $|f(x) - 0|$ is small, which is the same thing as saying $|f(x)|$ is small, which is the same thing as saying $|f(x)|$ is close to $0$.

If $L > 0$, the statement is false.  You can picture a function that is “undecided” between $L$ and $-L$ as a limit.  But then if you apply the absolute value, you get a function that has a limit of $L$.  And example would be
$$
    f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $x$ is rational} \\ -1 & \text{if $x$ is irrational} \end{cases}
$$
Then $|f(x)| = 1$, so $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = 1$.  But $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ cannot be $1$ because there are infinitely many irrational numbers arbitrarily close to $0$, and cannot be $-1$ because there are infinitely many rational numbers arbitrarily close to $0$.  So $f$ has no limit at $0$.

**EDIT** re your your question

> $L$ is said to be positive, isn't that a contradiction? $L=-1$ is not positive.

I'm not sure what you mean by *contradiction.*  If you mean that this example is not a counterexample to the given statement (that is, evidence of the statement's falsehood), remember that $L$ has to be the same throughout the statement.

When we say “The statement ‘If $\lim_{x\to a} |f(x)| = L$, then $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$ or $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) =-L$’ is false,” what we mean is: “there exists a function $f$ such that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$, but neither $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$ nor $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = -L$ are true”.  Substitute $L$ for $1$ (which is positive) and my function satisfies this.  I'm not changing $L$ to $-1$ anywhere; $-L$ is just another way of saying $-1$.

Comment: I thought about that, but the thing is that L is said to be positive, isn't that a contradiction? L=-1 is not positive